# object not getting new value in response in node.js response

Tags: node.js, express

i have the following:

```
var myObject={name:"name"};
var options={
hostname:'www.google.com',
port:80,
method:'GET'
};

var req=http.request(options,function(res){

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    myObject.serverResponse=chunk;
    console.log(myObject);
  });


});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);

});
```

req.end();

in the console i do not get serverResponse key/value pair. I just receive the original object. Where i am getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var serverResponse = '';
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    serverResponse += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function () {
    try {
      myObject.serverResponse = JSON.parse(serverResponse);
      console.log(myObject);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: no i am getting body. google is just a example to hide the actual url

Comment: Are you to say that the server response JSON string? You should call the JSON.parse() to get it. Look at the above code.